# Derivative and Integral of $\pi(x)$ (primes before $x$)?

Tags: calculus

What's the derivative and indefinite integral of $\pi(x)$, which gives the number of primes before $x$? I know there's no answer in terms of elementary functions, but is there an answer in terms of other functions or series?

Comment: I would suggest to add the fact that your function is $\pi(x)$ in the title, since it makes ur title more specific and it might help you get more help. :)

Comment: @Pinocchio Good idea :)

Comment: If by indefinite integral you mean antiderivative, then $\pi(x)$ has none since it has a jump discontinuity at each prime. Did you have some other meaning in mind?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez I just meant a function that I could use to evaluate the area between two points. It doesn't have to be the antiderivative, if theres another way to define the area function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would think about it.

You know that $\pi(x)$ is approximately equal to $\dfrac{x}{\ln(x)}$ for sufficiently large $x$ (specifically as $x \to \infty$) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

Thus, now you have expressed $\pi(x)$ as a continuous function that has a better chance of having derivatives and integrals. Now I would plug that into [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to see what the integral and derivatives look like.

Apparently, the derivative is $\dfrac{\ln(x) - 1}{\ln^2(x)}$.

However, the obvious disadvantages of this approach is that, the result is only valid for large values of $x$ , its an approximation and it only gives an asymptotic result.

Maybe if you provide more context or why you need this, a better answer might be possible.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your welcome! I think the key intuition is to note that a function that is discrete doesn't really become differentiable/integrable until you consider something so large that the sum of the discrete and small things starts to become an integral and add to something that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of π(x) would be 0 except when x is a prime, when it wouldn't exist since  π(x) takes a step at prime values of x.